# C++20: Force usage of designated initializers to emulate named function arguments

Tags: c++, c++20, designated-initializer

I am a big fan of using ad-hoc structs and designated initializers to emulate named parameters for my functions.

```cpp
struct Args {
    int a;
    int b;
};

int f(Args a) {
    return a.a + a.b;
}

int g() {
    return f({.a = 1, .b = 2}); // Works! That's what I want.
    return f({1, 2}); // Also works. I want to forbid this, though.
}
```

However, those structs can still be initialized by a positional initializer list. I.e., you can still call `f({1, 2})`.

I want to forbid this and force the caller to explicitly name the parameters also at the call-site.
How can I do so in C++20?

Comment: Note that `f({})` is another possible misuse.

Comment: Have you considered [some form](https://godbolt.org/z/91qqrPcGY) of strong typing, instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is just code review. Tell people to use designated initializers. Designated initializers are awesome, people like using them. This is really more of a social problem than a technical one.

If you really want to give a nudge, you could always stick in some truly awful data members first, like so:

```cpp
class Args {
    struct Key { explicit Key() = default; };
    struct StopIt { StopIt(Key) { } };

public:
    StopIt asdfjkhasdkljfhasdf = Key();

    int a;
    int b;
};
```

`Args` is still an aggregate, we just have this extra leading data member spelled with whatever came out when I just banged on my keyboard. It has a default member initializer - however that initializer is private to `Args` and only `Args` knows how to construct it.

So the user *cannot*<sup>†</sup> correctly provide an initializer for that particular member, they have to rely on the default member initializer to initialize it correctly. And since it goes first, they have to rely on designated initialization in order to be able to initialize any of the other members.

But also... this is kind of a silly thing to write? Just tell people to use designated initialization.

---

<sup>†</sup>Technically, they could write `f({Args().asdfjkhasdkljfhasdf, 1, 2})` in this case, but this seems like we're going for absurdity or spite at this point.

Comment: I guess, one should use `[[no_unique_address]]` for `StopIt`, but except for that this sounds like a solution to my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Also, the `f({Args().asdfjkhasdkljfhasdf, 1, 2})` could probably be blocked by giving `StopIt` a deleted copy constructor

Comment: @Vogelsgesang The solution to your problem is to tell people to use designated initializers. This is just for fun. Don't actually do this.

Comment: My actual use case for this would be a ProtoBuf generator: I want to enable usage of designated initializers to construct ProtoBuf messages. At the same time, I don't want users to rely on the order of members in the generated classes, as people should still be able to evolve their ProtoBuf definitions.

Given the ProtoBuf generator would be shipped to other teams/organizations, I can't review the code using it. And since this is generated code, I am not really concerned about the readability of this solution

Comment: I think you can also use inheritance here.  https://godbolt.org/z/9K548enee

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont That's a much better solution, but also less fun. Although you can write `foo({BlockedBracedInit<Args>{}, 1, 2})` just fine (although, again, if you find yourself writing something that basically says "don't write me"... )

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Actually worse because you can write `foo({}, 1, 2})`